# ColdFusion 9 CFCHART CFCHARTSERIES Issue

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart, cfoutput

I'm displaying a chart with one or more line series.  The data comes from a query and works correctly if there is more than on series on the chart.  However, if only one series is returned it is not displaying correctly.

Here's the code used:

```
<cfchart format="flash" tipstyle="mouseover" showlegend="yes" xaxistitle="Date" yaxistitle="Hits" chartwidth="1200" chartheight="300">
    <cfoutput query="qryReport" group="APP_SYS_NR">
        <cfchartseries serieslabel="#qryReport.APP_NA#" type="line">
        <cfoutput>
            <cfchartdata item="#DateFormat(qryReport.CDR_DT, "mm/dd/yyyy")#" value="#qryReport.TOT_HIT_CNT#">               
        </cfoutput>
        </cfchartseries>
    </cfoutput>
</cfchart>
```

The blacked out area at the top of this chart lists the keys for what the two lines represent:
[image: Working Chart]

In this chart (when there is only one APP_SYS_NR returned), instead of only having a single label, all the dates are turned into labels.  Obviously not what I want:
[image: Broken Chart]

**Edit: I've traced this to the showlegend attribute of cfchart.  According to Adobe, it's whether to display the legend if the chart contains more than one data series.  I guess when it contains only one data series, it completely craps itself and does the data points in the legend.  I tested on ColdFusion 9 and ColdFusion 10.**

Comment: Please elaborate on "not display correctly".  Specify what you would like to see and what you actually see.

Comment: Looks at the two charts above.  It's quite obvious the second one is displaying incorrectly.  It should not have all those dates listed at the top like they are a series.  Instead it should look just like the first chart, but with one items listed at the top (where the blacked out portion is in the first image).

Comment: Can't you just set showlegend to false?  I mean... is your problem the dozens of date legend items?

Comment: Yes, I've come up with a solution.  First checking to see how many applications are in the query, then setting legend to yes/no based on that.  If it's no, I display a chart title with the name of the single application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to set showlegend to no when there is only a single series to display.  Instead you should use a chart title in that instance.  See the following modified code:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.blnShowLegend = "no">
<cfset VARIABLES.strChartTitle = "#qryReport.APP_NA#">
<cfif ListLen(URL.lstApps) GT 1>
    <cfset VARIABLES.blnShowLegend = "yes">
    <cfset VARIABLES.strChartTitle = "">
</cfif>
<cfchart format="flash" title="#VARIABLES.strChartTitle#" tipstyle="mouseover" style="appstats" showlegend="#VARIABLES.blnShowLegend#" xaxistitle="Date" yaxistitle="Hits" chartwidth="1200" chartheight="300">
    <cfoutput query="qryReport" group="APP_SYS_NR">
        <cfchartseries serieslabel="#qryReport.APP_NA#" type="line">
        <cfoutput>
            <cfchartdata item="#DateFormat(qryReport.CDR_DT, "mm/dd/yyyy")#" value="#qryReport.TOT_HIT_CNT#">               
        </cfoutput>
        </cfchartseries>
    </cfoutput>
</cfchart>
```